# How to run both default renderer method and items renderer method for few columns in extjs grid?

Tags: extjs

I'm creating grid as follows. I want to change the style of the row depending on a condition
Also, the date column should have value in format -> 'd.m.Y'. If condition gets true, I want to change the color of the row. But because date column has its own renderer method, the default renderer doesn't work.
How can we run both the renderer methods?

```
columns : {
        defaults : {
            renderer : function(value, meta, record) {

                if (record.get('status') === false) {
                    meta.style = "color:#FF0000;";
                }
                return value;
            }
        },
        items : [  {
            text : 'Number',
            dataIndex : 'number',
            flex : 1
        }, {
            text : 'Type'),
            dataIndex : 'type',
            flex : 1
        }, {
            text : 'Date',
            dataIndex : 'date',
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d.m.Y'),
            flex : 1
        }]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default renderer is only called when you don't have a renderer in a column, you can just make a renderer in the date column that format the date and applies the meta style as well.

```
columns: {
    defaults: {
        renderer: function(value, meta, record) {

            if (record.get('status') === false) {
                meta.style = "color:#FF0000;";
            }
            return value;
        }
    },
    items: [{
            text: 'Number',
            dataIndex: 'number',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Type',
            dataIndex: 'type',
            flex: 1
    },
    {
        text: 'Date',
        dataIndex: 'date',
        renderer: function(value, meta, record) {
            if (record.get('status') === false) {
                meta.style = "color:#FF0000;";
            }
            return Ext.Date.format(value, 'd.m.Y');
        },
        flex: 1
    }]
}
```

**Using renderer function from controller**

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.GridController', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
            alias: 'controller.gridcontroller',
            dateRenderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                if(record.get('status') === false) {
                    meta.style = "color:#FF0000;";
                }
                return Ext.Date.format(value, 'd.m.Y');
            },
})

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    controller: 'gridcontroller',
    columns:
    //other properties...
    {
        text: 'Date',
        dataIndex: 'date',
        renderer: 'dateRenderer',
        flex: 1
    }
    //other properties...
})
```

**Fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2trg)**

Comment: If I had multiple date columns, then also I have to repeatedly add this condition in the items rendered method?

Comment: Basically yes, but you can create a renderer function in your controller and just pass it as a string to your columns renderer, see my edited answer

Comment: That worked..thanks. But can I sort this grid in descending order of the date?